# C# LINQ Oracle date Functions

Tags: c#, linq, oracle, date

I am trying to generate a sql statement to be used in Oracle11g, using linq.

The problem arises when using dates:

C# code:

```
DateTime convertedMinStartDateForEvent = Convert.ToDateTime(minStartDateForEvent);
DateTime convertedMinEndDateForEvent = Convert.ToDateTime(minEndDateForEvent);

var query = (from myTableRec in uow.myTable
             where myTableRec.startdate >= convertedMinStartDateForEvent && myTableRec.endDate < convertedMinEndDateForEvent
```

The SQL generated by linq gives

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE start_date > '24/11/2012 00:00:00' and end_date < '28/11/2012 00:00:00'
```

This causes an oracle error: ORA-01830 -  date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Adding TO_DATE to the query fixes the ORA-01830, as it is converting the string to a oracle date whilst now knowing the date format.

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE start_date > TO_DATE('24/11/2012 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and end_date < TO_DATE('28/11/2012 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

So, is there a way to add TO_DATE to LINQ (for oracle)?
If not, please tell me how to work around this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Did you use EntityFramework provider for Oracle? Or what linq did you use?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov
I am using Mindscape Lightspeed ORM
Thanks

Comment: @user1079925, Where does `'24/11/2012 00:00:00'` come from ? is it a from a `DateTime` varible ? or a `string` ? Can you provide the C# code as well ?

Comment: @Cade - added C# code as requested

Comment: @user1079925: You will have to file a bug with Mindscape. The problem is in their LINQ query provider.

Comment: @Cade - I should add that the minStartDateForEvent and minEndDateForEvent are passed in via jquery POST (using MVC3) as a string

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whether this will actually work, but this is what I'd try:

```
var query =  from myTableRec in uow.myTable
             where myTableRec.startdate >= convertedMinStartDateForEvent.Date
                && myTableRec.endDate < convertedMinEndDateForEvent.Date
```

(I've edited the query to refer to `myTableRec` - I suspect the code you posted wasn't your real code.)

You may even want to add the `Date` part to *all* references:

```
var query =  from myTableRec in uow.myTable
             where myTableRec.startdate.Date >= convertedMinStartDateForEvent.Date
                && myTableRec.endDate.Date < convertedMinEndDateForEvent.Date
```

*Hopefully* this will add the appropriate `TO_DATE` calls to the generated SQL. I agree with the comment that this sounds like a bug in the LINQ provider though.

Comment: Thanks for the input - your solution puts a TRUNC() around the database field but still renders the c# variable as a string in the generated SQL (no TO_DATE).  I suspect Jon (and yourself) are right in that it is a bug in Mindscape Lightspeed.  I've raised the issue with them and will update this question with a solution when they have responded.